# Problem updating a JComboBox in java swing

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jcombobox

I have the Categories method where I fill the JComboBox data through the database

```
public void categorias() 
    {
        int i=0;
        
        String [] categorias = new String [999];
        Conexion con = new Conexion();
        
        String sql = "select distinct categoria from item order by categoria";
        Statement st;

        try {
            Connection conexion = con.crearConexion();
            st = conexion.createStatement();
            ResultSet result = st.executeQuery(sql);
            
            while (result.next()) {
                categorias[i] = result.getString(1);
                i++;
            }
            
            for (String cat : categorias) {
                cmbCategoria.addItem(cat.toString());
                
            }
        
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }
```

, but the problem is that when updating I call the method of

```
cmbCategoria.removeAllItems();
categorias();
```

but in the first click it deletes everything and in the second click it already adds the data and updates but it is only a single method, I cannot find the error, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Stackoverflow is an English only site. Please restate your question in English.

Comment: Or please ask in  https://spanish.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, I forgot, I already edited it to English ty

Comment: No idea what you mean when you talk about the "first click" or "second click". In any case you code can be simplified. There is no need for the "categorias" array. In the while loop you just add the item to the combo box directly. Then get rid of the for loop.

Comment: Yes, I had it that way but they told me I have to use a .setModel to update and "first click" is when I press 1 time and call these methods
cmbCategory.removeAllItems ();
categories ();
but the comboBox appears without items and does not execute the categories () method;
and when I give the second click it appears as I want.

Comment: Still have no idea what you are "clicking"? So I still don't know what first click or second click means. *they told me I have to use a .setModel to update* - your code is not using setModel(). In any case you can still create an new DefaultComboBox model, add each item to the model and then use setModel(). So there is still no need for the array.

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data to replace the DB.